# I am not able to see my rosolved promise value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the smallest range. I am going to paste the link for a better understanding of my problem.

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/smallest-range-i/

I currently study Promise structures so I just wanted to use some promises in my code in order to make my code faster at the same time.

Here is my code;

```js
function smallestRangeI(A, K) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (A.length > 0) {
            resolve(A);
        } else {
            reject(0);
        }
    }).then(res => {
        const biggest = Math.max.apply(null, A);

        const biggestTotal = biggest - K;

        const smallest = Math.min.apply(null, A);

        const smallestTotal = smallest + K;
        
        res = biggestTotal < smallestTotal ? 0 : biggestTotal - smallestTotal;

        return res;
        
    }).catch(err => err);
}
```

The problem is my output. It is still pending. But it has fulfilled status which is completed. Also, my Promise Result looks okay. But I can't reach my resolved promise value which has to be a number(0) according to my input.

My input: `console.log(smallestRangeI([1], 2));`

Note: I am open to suggestions which means, please feel free to correct me about my code. I want to write clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `smallestRangeI` is promise function. So the result will be promise type. If you want to get the result, you should resolve the function result.

```js
function smallestRangeI(A, K) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (A.length > 0) {
      resolve(A);
    } else {
      reject(0);
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      const biggest = Math.max.apply(null, A);

      const biggestTotal = biggest - K;

      const smallest = Math.min.apply(null, A);

      const smallestTotal = smallest + K;

      res = biggestTotal < smallestTotal ? 0 : biggestTotal - smallestTotal;

      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => err);
}

smallestRangeI([1], 2)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

Leetcode expects the return value to be *the answer*, not a Promise that resolves to the answer. Since you can't change how Leetcode judges the code, and since you can't "unwrap" the Promise for it, you'll have to avoid Promises.

The Promises aren't doing anything remotely useful here anyway - even if you *did* have control over how Leetcode checks answers, it'd be better to remove the Promises.

```
var smallestRangeI = function(A, K) {
    const min = Math.min(...A);
    const max = Math.max(...A);
    const diff = max - min;
    return Math.max(diff - (2 * K), 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I currently study Promise structures so I just wanted to use some promises in my code in order to make my code faster at the same time.

You seem to be a bit misguided here. Promises don't make your code faster. Unlike some other languages with asynchronous features, Javascript is single-threaded, and promises don't actually run in the background, they just appear to. There's nothing to gain by using them.

In addition, also unlike some other languages, there's no way to "remove" or "unwrap" promises. You can chain them, but in the end you'll always have a promise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer!